# Correct way to handle exceptions when working with database

Tags: python, database, exception, tornado

When I am executing a simple query (I am using [tornado.database](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/database.html) module) I handle exceptions like this:

```py
try:
    self.application.db.execute('DELETE FROM table_one WHERE a = 1')
except Exception, e:
    logging.warning('DB exception: %s' % e)
    self.set_status(500)
    return
```

If I want to do a transaction though, it would be smart to rollback it in case of exception:

```py
try:
    self.application.db.execute('START TRANSACTION')
    self.application.db.execute('DELETE FROM table_one WHERE a = 1')
    self.application.db.execute('DELETE FROM table_two WHERE b = 2')
    self.application.db.execute('COMMIT')
except Exception, e:
    logging.warning('DB exception: %s' % e)
    self.set_status(500)
    self.application.db.execute('ROLLBACK')
    return
```

But what if *rollback* will cause an exception too (e.g. if connection fails)? Do I need to put a nested try-except block inside of the except block?

Comment: To start with, don't catch the general `Exception`. Instead try to catch whatever specific error you are ready to handle. As for rollback, if the connection is lost then (any normal) database will rollback automatically.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg tornado throws general `Exception`. Yes, it will, but default `wait_timeout` for MySQL is 28800 seconds, so other transactions on these tables would be blocked for that period of time, so I need to rollback explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing a nested try ... except block in except block is a solution. 
But I would go for using finally:

```
try:
  ...
except ... :

finally:
   # cleanup (close the connection, etc...)
```

I mean if the rollback failed, there is pretty much nothing else to do then log the exception and cleanup, right?

Answer (score 0):

better to check recommendations from [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#databaseerror)

according to PEP, main points I would like to highlight here:

- don't catch on general Exception
- don't raise general exceptions